# Jenkins | Publish Over SSH | Permission denied

Tags: jenkins, ssh, sudo, private-key, ssh-keygen

I want to execute *sudo commands* in Build server from Jenkins Master

**Steps Performed:**

- Jenkins Master: Plugin (SSH Plugin, Publish over ssh) added in Jenkins
- Build Server (remote machine): Produced the public/private key for sudo user "**john**" using ***ssh-keygen -t rsa -f jenkins_server_key***
- Build Server: Content of jenkins_server_key.pub append to authorized_keys
- Copy jenkins_server_key (private key) to Jenkins Master
- Jenkins Master: Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> SSH Plugin: Added private key value (jenkins_server_key), Hostname and Username details
- Jenkins Master: Validate Test Configuration - ***SUCCESS***
- Jenkins Master: Jenkins job added, "Execute Shell - ***ssh john@buildsrv.int date***"

> Error:

- ssh john@gbuildsrv01.int date
- Permission denied, please try again.
- Permission denied, please try again.
- john@gbuildsrv01.int: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).

Not sure what is the problem - No option to use tty due to restrictions.

Comment: You add public key to authorised_keys or to authorized_keys (the second is the correct one)?

Comment: @RomeoNinov: I have added public key to authorized_keys -> cat jenkins_server_key.pub >> authorized_keys

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.